# classifier after binary classifier

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have some images which contains some structure (building for example).

I have the pixel data and the labels data.

The labels data are in the form:

```
np.array([[0, nan, nan],
          [1, 2, 1],
          [1, 3, 2]])
```

> The first column means: is there or not a structure ? 1 or 0
>
> The second: what type is the structure ? types: 1,2,3
>
> The third: how many structures are there?

When we don't have a structure, all other values are nan.

So, for the example above we have:

> first line: no structure
>
> second line: we have a structure of type 2 and it is one
>
> third line: we have a structure of type 3 and there are two of them

So, first I am doing a binary classification to find out if we have a structure or not.

I am using vggnet with pretrained weights.

```
imagenet_weights = './vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
base_vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights=imagenet_weights, input_shape=input_shape)
last_layer = base_vgg16.output

x = Flatten()(last_layer)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

base_vgg16.trainable = False
model_vgg16 = Model(base_vgg16.input, preds)
```

and for training I am using 3kfold and data augmentation.

This gives 97% accuracy.

Now, I want to make a classification in order to find out the type, based on the binary classification results.

So , I have :

```
pred_val = model.predict(X_val)
```

**Now, I am not sure how to proceed.**

What to use as input for the classifier.

I tried:

```
X_train = X_train[np.where(pred_val >= 0.5), :]
```

or

```
pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
X_train = X_train[np.where(pred_train.squeeze() >= 0.5), :]
```

( I am not sure if it has any meaning to predict on train data)

Now, however I run the second network, I am always receiving awful results.

```
Val_loss is almost steady around (10-11)
Train_loss is around 10-12

Val_acc is almost steady around (0.25-0.35)
Train_acc is 0.28-0.38
```

For the second network:

```
 inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
 x = Flatten()(inputs)
 x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
 x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
 preds = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)      
 model = Model(inputs, preds)
```

Whatever combinations I tried, more or less units ( I tried only a few like : `x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)`)
 or whatever batch size and optimizer and learning rate the result is the same.

Comment: Predicting on training data is one type of check, but it's merely the forward pass of your training process.  It's okay for getting a new training set, but why not simply filter the original training data, rather than the predictions?  Filter out all of the non-structure items.

Comment: I'm confused about how you're planning to predict the structure type; it appears that you're using *only* the predicted presence of the structure.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Prune:For your second comment,yes I am using only the presence of the structure.Which is an image.For your first comment, you suggest doing something like: X_train=X_train[np.where(y_train_labels[:,1] != 'nan')], so taking from labels only the first column which gives the type?

Comment: @Prune:Even if I try filtering the original data, I still receive these results..

Comment: I suggest taking only those training items with `1` in the first label column.

Comment: I re-read all of this and found my first error -- you *do* have complex training data: the images.  However, there is nothing that automatically guarantees that your input data has statistically discernible classes, or that your chosen model is capable of making those distinctions.  Since you give neither in your posting, there's not much more we can do to help.  Real research is mostly spent in experimenting to find the best model for each particular application; you seem to be in a similar position.

Comment: @Prune:Ok, thanks for your comments.